# Postgres, aggregate function and ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by, array-agg

The statement works for me:

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, array_agg(d.start_date) date, array_agg(d.id) ids
FROM event e JOIN event_date d ON e.id = d.event_id
GROUP BY e.id
```

I receive the results

| id | title | dates | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First Event | {2022-06-05,2022-10-05} | {1,2} |
| 2 | Second Event | {2022-07-05} | {3} |

I want to order events by *start_date*. For that, I add `ORDER BY d.start_date DESC` to the statement:

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, array_agg(d.start_date) date, array_agg(d.id) ids
FROM event e JOIN event_date d ON e.id = d.event_id
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY d.start_date DESC
```

And I receive the error message:

> ERROR: column "d.start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
> used in an aggregate function LINE 4: ORDER BY d.start_date DESC

I don't understand it. `array_agg` **is** an aggregate function. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you want the values in the array to be sorted?

Comment: no, I want the event to be sorted by start_date

Comment: "d.start_date" is used in an aggregate function, but it is *also* used in an ORDER BY, which is not an aggregate.

Comment: Since an event can have multiple start_date, which one do you want it sorted by?

Comment: I want an event, not a start_date.
First Event has to start_dates {2022-06-05,2022-10-05}

Comment: look here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxyr5QhFXi3ReJ5UvQ9tH6/0
I want to group by event id and aggregate start_dates

Comment: That's precisely what jjanes asked. You want to sort the events by start_date - but by **which** start_date if there are multiple for each event. In your sample data the first event has the two start dates. One before the start date of the second even and one after the start date of the second event. What is the sort order you are after?

Comment: I doesn't matter how many start days has an event. I want to sort all start days of all events. Look here the column start_date

Comment: "*I want to sort all start days of all events*" does not make any sense, given your current query which returns only on row for each event.  You should [edit] your question and add some sample input data and the expected output based on that.

Comment: please look here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxyr5QhFXi3ReJ5UvQ9tH6/0

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work

```
SELECT e.id, e.title, array_agg(d.start_date ORDER BY d.start_date ASC) AS dates 
FROM event e JOIN event_date d ON e.id = d.event_id 
GROUP BY e.id 
ORDER BY dates ASC
```